# Send email via SMTP Mail server

Tags: powershell, email, smtp, windows-server-2012, smtpclient

I have installed SMTP Virtual Server in windows server 2012 r2. Later I have used following PowerShell script to send the email. Which was successful

```js
$email = "xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com" 
 
$pass = "xxxxxxx" 
 
$smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com" 
$smtpPort = "25" 
 
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$msg.From = "$email"  
$attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment("C:abcd/123.txt");
$msg.Attachments.Add($attachment);
$msg.To.Add("xxxx@xxxxx.com") 
$msg.BodyEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode 
$msg.SubjectEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode 
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true   
$msg.Subject ="List of users" 
$msg.Body=$msg.Body = "<h2> hi everyone </h2> 
$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$email", "$pass"); 
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

here my question is can I send email without using from address in the above script(Is there any chance to save from email address and credentials somewhere in SMTP virtual server settings so that script can take credentials directly). I don't want to use from email address and credentials in above script

Comment: You can use export-clixml on server to store the credentials object  - it will not be transferable between servers, but in can work in Your scenario. Moreover - there are many discussions about storing credential objects in secure manner over internet.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Send-MailMessage?view=powershell-5.1) instead of manual .NET manipulation:

```
$Creds = Import-CliXml -Path 'C:\mycreds.xml'

$MailArgs = @{ 'SmtpServer'  = 'smtp.office365.com'
               'Port'        = 25

               'To'          = 'xxxx@xxxxx.com'
               'From'        = $Creds.UserName
               'Subject'     = 'List of users'

               'Attachments' = 'C:\abcd\123.txt'
               'Body'        = '<h2> hi everyone </h2>'
               'Encoding'    = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode
               'BodyAsHtml'  = $true

               'UseSsl'      = $true
               'Credential'  = $Creds
             }
Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
```

And you would create your `$Creds` object as follows:

```
Get-Credential -Credential 'xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com' | Export-CliXml -Path 'C:\mycreds.xml'
```

There are a couple extra options you might be interested in (such as notification of delivery) you can read about in the doc linked above.

Additionally, your password is encrypted when exported using `Export-CliXml` specific to that device and account [utilizing DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx#windataprotection-dpapi_topic01).